# Catching all uncaught exceptions in C++/WinRT

Tags: exception, c++-winrt

I created a new C++/WinRT UWP project (type: `Blank App (C++/WinRT)`) and modified the default `App()` constructor to look like this:

```cpp
App::App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Suspending({ this, &App::OnSuspending });

    UnhandledException([this](IInspectable const&, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs const& e)
    {
        // just debug code, I want to place logging here in the actual program
        Windows::UI::Popups::MessageDialog dialog(L"Hello World", L"Hello World");
        dialog.ShowAsync();
    });                           
}
```

and I thought above code would always be invoked whenever an exception is thrown that is unhandled by my code.

---

I further modified the `OnLaunched` code to always throw an exception, e.g.

```cpp
void App::OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs const& e)
{
    Frame rootFrame{ nullptr };
    rootFrame.GoForward(); // force exception

    ...
```

but the exception handler from the `App` constructor is not invoked.

---

What am I doing wrong?
Is there a way to always execute some specific code (e.g. logging) when an uncaught exception is thrown?

Comment: Are things different when explicitly throwing an error, e.g. `winrt::throw_hresult(E_POINTER);`?

Comment: @IInspectable yes, if I explicitly `winrt::throw_hresult` everything works fine, the unhandled exception handler is invoked.

Comment: I'm guessing that `rootFrame.GoForward()` causes a null pointer dereference, reported as an [SEH exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/structured-exception-handling). Those do not participate in C++ exception handling. You would have to set up an [exception filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-setunhandledexceptionfilter) for those.

Comment: @IInspectable thank you, that is helpful. Also thanks for providing the link about SEH exceptions, so I can learn more about the different exception types.